# How to managed facebook post in own database for better manipulation?

Tags: php, algorithm, facebook-graph-api, cron, facebook-php-sdk

Imagine I want to store in my database the facebook posts from a user/page for getting them and manipulate them simplier.

I will make a php script that will be launch every day for each user/page who will get the posts I don't already have in my database and insert them.

Now, on my front website, you can log in, and see your posts.

Now, you go on facebook, and modify one of your post.

Now you come again on my website, and obviously, you don't see the modification you did on facebook, because this modification is on facebook database and not in mine, and your posts a retrived from my Database.

Theorically, one of the solution will be that facebook has a "log" table for posts, where i can find something like "this posts has be updated" so i can update my table. **Something like that exist ?**

If not i have a second solution, at each posts send from my server to my website, update it automatically with facebook database (getById the post on fb an update it in my db) and after that send the posts to my website. **But this will be a mess and a lot of request for nothing.**

**So how can i do this ? Someone have already tried this ? Or only directly manage the posts from facebook database ?**

Thanks =)

Comment: You can directly access FB so why cause yourself issues by trying to store it locally

Comment: https://developers.facebook.com/docs/graph-api/webhooks (should cover posts updates as well I think.)

Comment: @RiggsFolly => for many reason : 
- if for some reason fb is down => you can continu to access to all data
- facebook delete some of the data after long time (posts can be delete after 3 years for exemple)
- AND BIG REASON : get data trought facebook is very limited : getting only 100 data, or between two timestamp but cannot not exceeded 83 days => mutliple request if you want get datas between 2 years, you can get some data only pro day, so if you want get them pro month, like 5 months => but remember you cannot because only 83 days for max interval.

Comment: @CBroe this seems to be what i search ! Thanks !!

Comment: @CBroe if you can post this as answer i can accept it

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Facebook has a mechanism to send updates to you, called webhooks.

https://developers.facebook.com/docs/graph-api/webhooks

You can subscribe to several fields for users or pages, among them the feed.

You’ll have to check if it delivers updates to already existing posts as well - but I think it should, would make little sense if it didn’t.